# howto prevent www-authenticate header when using passport-http Basic + passport-local combination

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

Hi I want to support both formbased authentication and http basic authentication in my app. Everything works as expected except when I use form based auth via angularjs with wrong credentials.

Instead of having my angular code handle the 401, the browser shows the BASIC auth dialog, caused by the WWW-Authenticate header.

How can I prevent that header from being added when the local strategy is used? 
Or how can I support both mechanisms in a different way?

I use the following route in my express based app.

```
api.post('/authenticate', passport.authenticate(['local', 'basic'], { session: false }), function (req, res) {
```

This enables both authentication methods on that url. I repeat, when I use wrong credentials using formbased it shows me the basic auth dialog (I don't want that).

Following is how I registered the strategies.

```
passport.use(new BasicStrategy({ realm: 'Authentication failed. Wrong username or password.'}, verifyLocalUser));
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(verifyLocalUser));
```

This is how my verifyUser method looks like...

```
var verifyLocalUser = function (username, password, next) {
    User.findOne({
        username: username
    }).select('fullname admin username password').exec(function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        if (user && user.comparePasswords(password)) {
            return next(null, user);
        } else {
            next(null, false, { message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong username or password.' });
        }
    });
}
```

Does anyone know how to support multiple authentication methods using passport.js?

For completeness, this is the angular code which authenticates me...

```
authFactory.signIn = function (username, password) {
        return $http.post('/api/authenticate', {
            username: username,
            password: password
        }).then(function (res) {
            AuthToken.setToken(res.data.token);
            return res.data;
        }, function (res) {
            console.warn(res);
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
next(null, false, { message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong username or password.' });
```

You can use this:

```
cb(new YourCustomError())
```

And "YourCustomError" can have a message, for me mine "YourCustomError" looks like:

```
class HttpError extends Error {
  constructor (msg = 'Invalid Request', status = 400) {
    super(msg)
    this.status = status
  }
}

class Forbidden extends HttpError {
  constructor (msg = 'Forbidden') {
    super(msg, 403)
  }
}
```

Or probably `new Error(<message>)` will work properly for you, too

Answer (score 0):

To override passport-http's BasicStrategy setting the WWW-Authenticate header.

`BasicStrategy.prototype._challenge = () => 401;`

This function by default returns `'Basic realm="' + this._realm + '"'`, which sets the WWW-Authenticate to this value. See their [code in Github](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http/blob/master/lib/passport-http/strategies/basic.js#L106)